# Daisy chain two dell P2422H monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, daisychaining

I have a dell docking station and two P2422H monitors I need to daisy chain. The monitors do not have thunderbolt/usb-c ports. Is there a work around to daisy chain these monitors for extended display capabilities? Would a usb-a to usb-c adapter/converter work? Thanks!

Comment: Daisychain means, signal goes in, signal transfers through device, signal goes out. This requires a monitor that as a displayport out or usb-c/thunderbolt out port. There are splitter cables are an option for something like DVI-D or a USB Dockingstation that have multiple outputs. USB-A does not support display, so that will not work at all.